# Authentication ios 6 objective c

Tags: ios6, automatic-ref-counting, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am working on **iOS 6, ARC,storyboards** enable iphone app. I am trying to figure out log out functionality and what should happen when user wants to log out. I have a menu like Facebook and a log out option with in the menu. To mimic the menu I am using **ECSlidingViewController**.

What I really want to find out is, what actually should happen when user logs out in terms of bringing applicaition to it's launch state with nothing in memory.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

When user logs out you usually do the following:

1. Pop to the root view controller or (main menu / login screen).
2. Clear out all user data saved in db or userDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

You could use popToRootViewControllerAnimated: to have all your view controllers popped except the original root view controller and then the display will update.